# Expected of squared uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say $U$ is a uniform distribution given by $U\sim\text{Unif}(0,1)$. How can I compute the $E(U^2)$.

This is the definition: $\int_0^1 u^2 f_U(u)du$.

In the lecture the guy takes $f_U(u)$ to be 1. How can  you put it as 1 when is in the integral and a function of the every variable $u$.

Comment: $$\operatorname E[\varphi(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x) f(x)\, \operatorname dx$$
where $X$ is any continuous random variable with pdf $f(x)$. A similar formula with summation gives the expected value of any function of a discrete random variable.

Comment: The density of a random variable uniformly distributed between $a$ and $b$ is $f(x)=\dfrac1{b-a}$ on that interval so $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)\, dx =1$. Now let $a=0$ and $b=1$

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

Look at $\text{Var}(U)$.

---

It is possible. Ignore the problem at the moment, and consider the function $y = 2$. Does this make sense to you? I hope so, it is a constant, horizontal line at $2$. Similarly, we could have written it as $y = f(x)$. Notice that this means $f(x) =2$. It does not matter that there is no $x$. It still makes sense that it is a constant function at $2$.

This is the same situation as the uniform situation,
$f_U(u) = 1$ 
and hence
$$E[U^2] = \int_0^1 u^2f_U(u)\,du = \int_0^1u^2\cdot 1\,du =\frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: Yes, I see. **Always** include relevant information that you have.

Comment: But the distribution I mentioned is not constant.

Comment: The density function, the **pdf** is constant. $\text{Unif}(0,1)$ implies that the random variable has a pdf $f_U(u) = 1$ when $0\leq u\leq 1$.

Comment: I can't intuitively understand this. This means that each value in the interval has a probability 1?

Comment: That is not what pdf means. Loosely speaking $P(X\in dx) = f(x)\,dx$, so the density is $f(x) = P(X\in dx)/dx$.

Comment: Sorry it is still unclear.  I know that pdf means probability per unit length as you mentioned. But for every $u$ in $U$, how can the probability per unit length be 1?

Comment: If you want to think about it that way, then I think it might help you to verify that $\int_0^1 f(u)\,du = 1$.

Comment: That integral is over the whole interval and it is being 1 makes sense. But now you take $u^2f(u)$. Now for each value of $u$ over the interval, f(u) is not 1?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Loosely speaking, the $pdf$ is the rate of change of probability.  Its the gradient of the CDF, not the probability itself.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia I don't quite understand your question, $f_U(u)$ ***is*** $1$, so that for any $0\leq c\leq 1$, $f_U(c) = 1$.